# Laravel - AWS s3 Can't Connect

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

I'm trying to get url. Code below;

```
return Storage::url('uploads');
```

My .env file informations are correct. (I tried to test aws informations, on my other project. And it worked well)

Here's my error:

```
ErrorException: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in file /Users/blablabla/Valet/prospectivy/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/RetryMiddleware.php on line 146
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: If you are certain that it is working for you in another project and nothing is different, did you clear and set the config/cache after updating your AWS creds in the .env?

Comment: I used: php artisan config:clear php artisan cache:clear  nothing has changed...

Comment: Did you install league with composer and if so, is it configured correctly?

Comment: yeah, project is working with no problem. my .env and composer confiurations are correct.

Comment: did you try it in this kind of format instead?  ```Storage::disk('s3')->url('uploads')```

Comment: I found problem. I got "php-aws-sdk" and league sdk at the same time. And It gives error.